# 動的計画法でナップサック問題を解く

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム, データ構造

動的計画法を使ってナップサック問題を解きたいのですがなぜか不正解になります。
なぜでしょうか?

１から配列が始まっている(1origin)として解いてみようと思い下記のコードを書いてみたのですが正解になりません。
多くの解説ではdpテーブルの遷移を

```
dp[i][p]: i-1 番目までの品物から重さが p を超えないように選んだときの、価値の総和の最大値
```

としていますが、これを
i番目(i-1ではない)までの品物から重さがpを超えないように選ぶ時の価値の総和の最大値とすることはできるのでしょうか?

https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_d

> 問題文
>
> N個の品物があります。 品物には 1,2,…,N と番号が振られています。 各 i (1≤i≤N) について、品物 i の重さは wi
>   で、価値は vi です。
>
> 太郎君は、N個の品物のうちいくつかを選び、ナップサックに入れて持ち帰ることにしました。 ナップサックの容量は W
>   であり、持ち帰る品物の重さの総和はW以下でなければなりません。
>
> 太郎君が持ち帰る品物の価値の総和の最大値を求めてください。
>
> 制約 入力はすべて整数である。  1≤N≤100  1≤W≤105  1≤wi≤W  1≤vi≤109

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using lli = long long int;
template <typename T>
bool chmax(T& a, T b) {
    if (b > a) {
        a = b;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

lli n, w;
std::vector<std::pair<lli, lli>> vec;
std::vector<std::vector<lli>> dp;


int main() {
    std::cin >> n >> w;
    vec.assign(n+1, {0, 0});
    for (lli i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> vec[i].first >> vec[i].second;
    }
    dp.assign(n+1, std::vector<lli>(w+1, 0));

    for (lli i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (lli p = 0; p <= w; p++) {
            if (p >= vec[i].first) {
                chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p-vec[i].first] + vec[i].second);
            }
            else {
                chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p]);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << dp[n][w] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: (1)読み込みは0originだが`vec[0]`を使っていない (2) elseにある`chmax`は条件に関わらず行う必要があるのではないか(`dp[i-1][p]`が最も大きいかもしれない)といった点が気になりました。

Comment: 2つ目のchmaxはどのような遷移になっているのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using lli = long long int;
template <typename T>
bool chmax(T& a, T b) {
    if (b > a) {
        a = b;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

lli n, w;
std::vector<std::pair<lli, lli>> vec;
std::vector<std::vector<lli>> dp;


int main() {
    std::cin >> n >> w;
    vec.assign(n+1, {0, 0});
    for (lli i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //std::cin >> vec[i].first >> vec[i].second;
        std::cin >> vec[i+1].first >> vec[i+1].second;
    }
    dp.assign(n+1, std::vector<lli>(w+1, 0));

    for (lli i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (lli p = 0; p <= w; p++) {
            if (p >= vec[i].first) {
                chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p]);
                chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p-vec[i].first] + vec[i].second);
            }
            else {
                chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p]);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << dp[n][w] << std::endl;
}
```

このコードでACすることを確認しました。おそらくペアの配列への入力の仕方がおかしかったのだと思われます。

Comment: 基本的な質問ですがどうしてchmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p])はifの条件に関係なく必要なのでしょうか

Comment: chmax(dp[i][p], dp[i-1][p])を入れなかった場合のコードのテストをしていないので、もしかしたらこの一行は無くてもACするかもしれません。ただ、私がDPの問題を解く時の癖で、DPを更新する上での「必要条件」としてのコードは書くようにしているというだけです...。

Comment: d[i-1][p] は i 番目の品物を使わなかった場合の最小コストで、dp[i-1][p-vec[i].first] + vec[i].second は i 番目の品物を使った場合の最小コストです。else の中では i 番目の品物を使えないので後者を考慮する必要はありませんが、そうでないときには両方を考慮する必要があるということです。